# Continious update of matplotlib plot in Jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am working on a `Jupyter Notebook` and I am using the following `ipywidget` to set a threshold value:

```
Thr = widgets.IntSlider(value=-17, min=-30, max=-13, step=1, description='Threshold: ', disabled=False, continuous_update=True, orientation='horizontal', readout=True, readout_format='d')
Thr
```

Next, I am masking a `numpy array` using that value with:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
test= ma.masked_less_equal(S_images[0], Thr.value)
```

And finally I plot the result with:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (15,15))
plt.imshow(test[0], cmap='gray')
```

The `ipywidget` is in a different `Jupyter cell` than the other code so when I change the value of `Thr` I have to manually run again the cell where the masking and ploting takes place.

My question is: I have always seen those interactive plots where you change a parameter (in my case the ipywidget `Thr`) and automatically the plot gets updated.

I see that `widgets.IntSlider` has a `continuous_update` parameter which seems to be close to what I want but still cannot get the behaviour I want.

Any idea if this is doable or possible?

**_ EDIT _**

Starting from the comment of ac24, I am adapting the example he proposes:

```
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import ipywidgets as ipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# setup figure
n = 10

out = ipy.Output()

# show random mesh
def update(idx):
    with out:
        clear_output()
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,5))
        h = ax.imshow(S_images[0]) # here I put my image
        h.set_data(np.ma.masked_less_equal(S_images[0], slider.value)) # here I set the task to masked accordint to the `slider.value`
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
        fig.canvas.draw()
        plt.show()

slider = ipy.IntSlider(min = 0, max = 10, orientation = 'vertical')
widget = ipy.interactive(update, idx = slider)

layout = ipy.Layout(
#     display = 'flex',
#                    flex_flow = 'row',
#                    justify_content = 'space-between',
#                    align_items = 'center',
                   )
widgets = ipy.HBox(children=(slider, out), layout = layout)
display(widgets)
```

The example works very nice and is just what I was looking for. However, I have a small question regargind the layout. Originally I am working with 3 Images so I would like to have them displayed as follows, each one with its slider next to it to do the task: (the image below is not real, just made it up to represent what I would like)

[image]

**EDIT 2**

in this occasion, the question is, once I select a value in the slider, I would write to geotiff that raster. For this I am using the following code:

```
with rasterio.open('/Path/20190331_VV_Crop') as src:
    ras_meta = src.profile

with rasterio.open('/path/Threshold.tif', 'w', **ras_meta) as dst:
    dst.write(X)
```

However, I am not sure how to reference the numpy array in `dst.write(X)`

Comment: There is a simple example here in another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58556700/control-of-layout-ipywidgets-in-jupyter-notebook/58561439#58561439). It should give the basics of the interact function and how to display the chart. The `continuous_update` parameter provides some different functionality, experiment with it in my example and see if you can figure out how it works.

Comment: @ac24 many thanks for the comment. If you add it as an answer I will be happy to accept it. I just have a small remark on the layout. I have edited my question to add the question. Could you comment on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've adapted the example I gave into a class, as you want to link a specific output and slider instance, but create multiple groups of them. Setting the layout of the output widget avoids the widget resizing all the time as you slide the slider.

```py
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import ipywidgets as ipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# setup figure
n = 10

class SliderAndImage():

    # show random mesh
    def update(self, idx):
        with self.out:
            clear_output()
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,5))
            h = ax.imshow(np.random.rand(n, n))
            h.set_data(np.random.rand(n, n))
            fig.canvas.flush_events()
            fig.canvas.draw()
            plt.show()

    def make_slider_and_image(self):

        self.out = ipy.Output(layout=ipy.Layout(width='200px', height='200px'))

        slider = ipy.IntSlider(min = 0, max = 10, orientation = 'vertical')
        widget = ipy.interactive(self.update, idx = slider)

        layout = ipy.Layout(
        #     display = 'flex',
        #                    flex_flow = 'row',
        #                    justify_content = 'space-between',
        #                    align_items = 'center',
                           )
        widgets = ipy.HBox(children=(slider, self.out), layout = layout)
        return widgets

children = []
for _ in range(3):
    widgets = SliderAndImage()
    children.append(widgets.make_slider_and_image())
display(ipy.HBox(children))
```

[image]

Comment: great example for interactive plotting. Many thanks

Comment: I have edited the question to add a small related question